# How to make a graph tangent to tops of another graph?

Tags: matlab, graph

I've got a graph: the velocity as a function of the rpm of a car. The actual graph consists of four subgraphs (one for each of the 4 gears of the car). I conjoined those sub-graphs with a for loop and some if statements. This resulting graph is shown below.

I need to add a graph which is tangent to all the tops of the graphs, like the red line. The final result would look like this:

[image: graph]

(It's now still without the red line, obviously...)

These are the coordinates where the tangent line would touch the graph: (17, 5130.36), (28, 3117.98), (39, 2239.37), (51, 1714.72).

Comment: You are solving the curve by eye, its going to be pretty difficult for a machine to do this. If you select the peaks of the curves you can use a polynomial solver to find the red curve?

Comment: You could also maybe look for drastic changes in the derivative of the data to find these peaks?

Comment: @Ben : I'm not really experienced with matlab(nor advanced mathematics) yet, i'm still a student.. :( I've read about the matlabs peaks funtion, would i be able to create that graph by using peaks? I would already be satisfied by something less pretty, like with a graph with three kinks in it, if it still touches all the bumps it's sufficient for me.

Comment: No peaks just returns a nice 2D mesh. Try using `roots` with the 4 points that it touches to generate a 4th order polynomial. Then you can create data for the line and plot it.

Comment: Man, if i knew it'd be this difficult to create a tangent line(in Autodesk inventor we draw them every day..) i'd have chosen another subject.. How would i use the roots function? fill in the coordinates i want the graph to touch?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an "[envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves))" of some form and you want an [envelope detector/extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector). See [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/envelope-extraction-using-the-analytic-signal.html). Normally the approach shown is used on oscillatory signals about zero, so I don't know how well it will work for you and you may need to shift your curve. Other methods are possible if you use knowledge about your system and interpolation.

Comment: @horchler Yeah that seems pretty to be what im trying to do, I tried to apply it to my graph but i dont have the knowledge of matlab yet to do this properly, i didnt succeed. but thanks for the help

Comment: @Bart, can you post the actual data? Where exactly are the boundaries between data from different gears?

Comment: @A.Donda : I'm sorry for my late reaction, i'd be really thankful if you could still help me.
These are the coordinates where the tangent line would touch the graph.
(17,5130.36)(28,3117.98)(39,2239.37)(51,1714.72)
The variables i used for plotting the graph are too complex to just post here, and i don't know how to properly isolate the relevant stuff out of the script.

Comment: I tried an answer, have a look. I also edited your question with the new information. One more question: You say velocity as a function of rpm, but the axis labels say, as far as I can tell, force as a function of velocity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know the tangent points,

```
x = [17 28 39 51];
y = [5130.36 3117.98 2239.37 1714.72];
plot(x, y, 'b.')
```

the solution is a simple interpolation

```
xs = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);
ys = spline(x, y, xs);
hold on
plot(xs, ys, 'r')
```

with the result:

[image]

I here used Matlab's standard cubic spline interpolation; depending on the properties of your data, other [interpolation functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/1-d-interpolation.html) might give better results. In particular, if you knew not only the positions of the tangent points but also the tangent slope, you could use that information to impose constraints on a piecewise polynomial interpolation.

Comment: Yes! that does the trick. At least, it works for this particular occasion when those coordinates are true. The point is, those coordinates I gave originate from a earlier calculation. If i fill in other data/variables from a car with a different gearbox, in the calculation it doesn't work, yet. But i think i can make that happen myself with your help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to provide a more general answer without knowing more details. One would need the full underlying data, optimally for more than one car.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I think I can make that happen myself with the help you gave me in your post. I see I said that a bit ambiguous. thanks again